# Why does compare of entities not work in subquery

Tags: java, jpa, entity, jpa-2.0

Can someone explain me, why this query is working in JPA:

```
SELECT e FROM Entry e JOIN e.tags tags WHERE tags IN :tags
```

e.tags is

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "entryList" )
private List<Tag> tags = new LinkedList<>();
```

So, I can compare the entities in tags with the entities in the parameter. But following doesn't work:

```
SELECT e FROM Entry e WHERE (SELECT COUNT(t) FROM Tag t JOIN t.entryList e2 WHERE e2 = e AND t IN :tags) = :size
```

There is no error, but no results are found. It is working correctly if I give a list of tag ids to parameter :tags and do following query:

```
SELECT e FROM Entry e WHERE (SELECT COUNT(t) FROM Tag t JOIN t.entryList e2 WHERE e2 = e AND t.id IN :tagIds) = :size
```

I spent hours until I came to this simple cause of the error and would be interested in knowing when it is possible to compare entities and when not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First query is not expected to work. Left side of conditional operator in IN expression cannot be entity. What can be used is enums, strings, numeric and date types. Allowed values for right side do depend about what is on left side. In JPA 2.0 specification this is told as follows:

```
in_expression::=   
    {state_field_path_expression | type_discriminator} **[NOT] IN**  
        { ( in_item {, in_item}* ) | (subquery) 
           |collection_valued_input_parameter }   
in_item ::= literal | single_valued_input_parameter
```

> The `state_field_path_expression` must have a string, numeric, date, time, timestamp, or enum value.
>
> The  literal and/or input parameter values must be like the same abstract
>   schema type of the `state_field_path_expression` in type.

Comment: But the first query works for me on JPA 2.1 and Glassfish 4.0. So I thought that also second should work.

Comment: Because of above mentioned reasons, both first and second query (ones that do use entity in comparison) are invalid what it comes to specification. That also didn't changed with JPA 2.1. If something works, that just because vendor decided (or purely accidentally implemented) handy extensions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the JPA soec allows objects in an IN.  Some providers may, but it may depend on which version you are using, if your object has a composite id, and what database you are using.

If it is not working, you could try the  latest release, or log a bug.